# consume wcf service using phonegap

Tags: wcf, cordova

I have created a wcf service and a phonegap application to consume wcf service.
Mywcf service doesn't debug when I deploy it using IIS, but it is run using "visual studio Development Server".
When I run my phonegap application success function runs but data shows "undefined" and then error msg displays.
My phonegap code is as under:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.getJSON("http://localhost:20999/MobileService.svc/GetProductCategories", {
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
},complete: function () {
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();},
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: 'json',
type: 'GET',
success: function (data) {
    alert("success");
    alert("Exito " + JSON.stringify(data));  },
error: function () {
alert('Something awful happened');
}});});
```

What is problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your success function try.

```
alert("Exito " + JSON.stringify(data[0]));  },
```

You may have to post code of your WCF service and set up the service to run through IIS instead of the port. It looks like the service is trying to return an object that you're not identifying with the data value.

Usually you have to do something like

```
alert("Exito " + JSON.stringify(data.[Object Name]));  },
```